# Generate graphs in R for certain correlations in a matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr, reshape2

I want to generate graphs between variables (columns) that have a correlation above and below a certain point as well as having a pvalue < 0.01. The graphs would be ggplot2 (line or bar) graphs plotting the two columns (variables) that correlate.

Here is the gist of my approach so far, with some dummy data, I would love a pointer in where to go next.

```
# Create some dummy data
df <- data.frame(sample(1:50), sample(1:50), sample(1:50), sample(1:50))
colnames(df) <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")

# Find correlations in the dummy data
df.cor <- cor(df)

# Make up some random pvalues for this example
x <- 0:1000
df.cor.pvals <- data.frame(sample(x/1000, 4), sample(x/1000, 4), sample(x/1000, 4), sample(x/1000,4))
colnames(df.cor.pvals) <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")

# Find the significant correlations
df.cor.extreme <- ((df.cor < -0.01 | df.cor > 0.01) & df.cor.pvals < 0.5)

# Ready data to for plotting
df$rownames <- rownames(df)
df.melt <- melt(df, id="rownames")

# I want to plot the combinations of variables that have a TRUE value
# in the df.cor.extreme matrix
```

Below is hardcoded example if var1 and var2 had a value of TRUE. I assume this is where I need some sort of loop to generate multiple plots where varA and varB are correlated.

```
ggplot(df.melt[(df.melt$variable=="var1" | df.melt$variable=="var2"),], aes(x=rownames, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: I don't understand why your data frame of p-values, `df.cor.pvals`, has 50 rows - shouldn't it be the same shape as `df.cor`?

Comment: You can get the matrix of correlations you're looking for using `df.cor.extreme <- df.cor < -0.01 | df.cor > 0.01`

Comment: Fixed my dummy data and incorporated your suggestion using the single logical operators.

Have also put in the first steps of graphing, just can't automate graphs for those TRUE values in the df.cor.extreme matrix.

Comment: @themartinmcfly I still confused about your final plot. You want to plot the original values when certain condition is satisfied. if cond(v1,v2) is ok , plot(what?) plot(v1)? plot(v1 vs v2)??

Comment: @agstudy My final plot is just an example if var1 and var2 happened to correlate. I want to plot every correlation that is significant. By multiple plots I mean a separate plot that compares the two correlating variables. The matrix df.cor.extreme (or df.core.sig in your example) contains the data saying which correlations are significant, but I am stuck on how to transfer this data into code that will generate plots for all of the correlations (the data set I am looking at will have 150+ plots).

Comment: @agstudy I have added a picture of the plot just for visualisation.

Comment: @themartinmcfly I update my answer after your clarification. Hope that   this answer your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in the comment by @DrewSteen , p-avlue must be the same shape of cor.

Here I supply a function that compute p-value matrix( it should exist a build-in function, in stats package)

```
pvalue.matrix <- function(x,...){
  ncx <- ncol(x)
  r <- matrix(0, nrow = ncx, ncol = ncx)
  for (i in seq_len(ncx)) {
    for (j in seq_len(i)) {
      x2 <- x[, i]
      y2 <- x[, j]
      r[i, j] <-  cor.test(x2,y2,...)$p.value
    }
  }
  r <- r + t(r) - diag(diag(r))
  rownames(r) <- colnames(x)
  colnames(r) <- colnames(x)
  r
}
```

Then you use the vectorize version of | and & like this

```
df.cor.sig <- (df.cor > 0.01 | df.cor < -0.01) & pvalue.matrix(df) < 0.5
```

the plot is classic with geom_tile

```
library(reshape2) ## melt
library(plyr)     ## round_any
 library(ggplot2) 
dat <- expand.grid(var1=1:4, var2=1:4)
dat$value <- melt(df.cor.sig)$value
dat$labels <- paste(round_any(df.cor,0.01) ,'(', round_any(pvalue.matrix(df),0.01),')',sep='')
ggplot(dat, aes(x=var1,y=var2,label=labels))+ 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour='white')+
 geom_text()
```

[image]

### Edit after OP clarification

```
plots <- apply(dat,1,function(x){
    plot.grob <- nullGrob()
    if(length(grep(pattern='TRUE',x[3])) >0 ){
      gg <- paste('var',c(x[1],x[2]),sep='')
      p <- ggplot(subset(df.melt,variable %in% gg ), 
            aes(x=rownames, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) +
            geom_line()
      plot.grob <- ggplotGrob(p)
    }
    plot.grob

})


library(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange,  plots)
```

[image]

Comment: This is so close to what I am looking for, I am going to experiment into expand.grid more. I think if I could get a data frame like
`variable1, variable2, significant;
 var1, var2, TRUE;
var1, var3, FALSE`

I would have a list of which correlations to graph and just need to loop or similar

Comment: @themartinmcfly you prefer to get data not the plot? can you append your answer with what you expect as data.frame?

Comment: Nice answer.  I was not familiar with the 'round_any' function.  So, I would only add for others in the same boat that you appear to be using the ggplot2, reshape2 and plyr packages to create the plot.

Comment: @agstudy, I am looking for multiple plots, one for each significant correlation between variables. I was surmising that a data frame with that data could be the next step

Comment: @MarkMiller thanks! I use the 3 packages! I forget to add it because I use it wasn't the origin question. I add the text just to check my answer. I update my answer .

Comment: @agstudy I have changed the formatting of the question so that it has multiplots written more clearly. I also want to thank you for the demonstration pvalue code, I have modified my own as it did not utilise cor.test and only did Pearson's.

Comment: @themartinmcfly I update my code you can give any method "pearson", "kendall", "spearman", to the p.value function.

Comment: @agstudy Very nice! Much better than having the calculations being done manually :)

Comment: @themartinmcfly what are you talking about, agstudy had to do it manually. :) +1 for gridExtra and work invested into this.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I meant using a table with critical values and subbing your r value into there. Or using an approximation. Agstudy's solution is much better.

Comment: side-note: you don't need `ggplotGrob`, if you keep it as a ggplot, you have the added benefit of `ggsave` compatibility.

Comment: @agstudy I have added an answer as an addition to yours, so if you are using this code you created yourself feel free to add mine.

Comment: @baptiste, thanks I am using ggsave with this function at the moment. Works well. It also works well by returning each plot to a collection of plots so that you can call any by plots[x].

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add an addition to @agstudy 's answer if you are doing this yourself.

If you play with the results of the function that generates a table of matrix indexes that you can apply the significance to. I.e. this line:

```
dat <- expand.grid(var1=1:4, var2=1:4)
```

Also remember that the hardcoded 4's in the line above are the length of your (square) grid. Anyway, you can ignore the generation of any duplicate graphs by doing some code like so:

```
# Find redunant pairs
dat <- data.frame(t(apply(dat, 1, function(x){
  if(x[1]-x[2] <= 0) {    # If > zero than pair has come before.
    -x                    # If = zero than pair is same 
  } else x
})))

# Remove redundant pairs
dat <- dat[dat$var1>0,]
```

Enjoy!